# Got error 28 from storage engine (disk full) but my disk are not full

Tags: mysql, disk-space-utilization

Basically MySQL is giving me many errors of "Got error 28 from storage engine" that means no more disk space is available.

The output of `df -h` is:

```
File system           Dim. Usati Disp. Uso% Montato su
/dev/md1               10G  7,9G  1,6G  84% /
tmpfs                 2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  176K  9,9M   2% /dev
tmpfs                 2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md2              683G  601G   48G  93% /home
```

Every filesystem here is not empty. Are there any other problem?

I am on
- a dedicated server  (debian 64bit )
- and the errors happens doing an heavy query

Comment: The title says "error 26" but the question says "error 28".  Is that a typo or did you get two different errors at different times?

Comment: sorry of course error 28

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be that your query makes MySQL create temporary tables. In the default configuration, these will be created alongside the other tables, which is likely on your `/` partition which has only 1.6GB left, and these tables can become larget than that really quickly.

Watch your free space while you do such a query.

See [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) about it.

Comment: indeed that query are made on pretty large table... I will try to free some spaces in /

Answer (score 3):

Two other possibilities:

1. Filesystems often reserve 5% of the space and return an error when it reaches 95% full.  Your `/home` is at 93%.
2. You get the same error message when you run out of inodes, even if you still have disk space left.  You can see inodes with `df -i`.

I think SvenW's answer is more likely to be *correct*.  His reasoning is sound and I have run into exactly the same issue myself.

You can figure out whether the query is going to use a temporary table by running `EXPLAIN <query>` in your MySQL instance, replacing `<query>` with the actual query.  You are looking for "Using temporary" in the `Extra` section.  Temporary tables will be written to disk if they are larger than `max_heap_table_size` and/or `tmp_table_size` in your `my.cnf`.

You can find what directory MySQL is using for temporary tables by looking at the `tmpdir` variable either in the running instance (`mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`) or in your `my.cnf` (`grep tmpdir my.cnf`).

Comment: Hm, Do mysql uses `/home` or `/` ? Anyway i will check `df -i` too later! thanks you too

Comment: MySQL uses whatever you have configured in `my.cnf` for `datadir`.  The default is `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: I have explain-ed my query, there is "using temporary; Using filesort" in the extra field. My `tmpdir` var is `/tmp`. But I have 1,6GB free on `/` how is that possible